# Montero cranks but won't run after timing belt replacement

Tags: troubleshooting, mitsubishi, cranks-wont-run, montero

This is a 2004 Mitsubishi Montero Sport 3.5 L.

I changed the timing belt and water pump, as well as the auto tensioner and pulleys.

I aligned all the timing marks and put it all back together. Now it cranks, but won't start.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you recheck the timing? Is it setting a p0340 or similar?